# Danish (?) lyrics for "All that Jazz" by Julie Steincke

Tags: lyrics

Some time ago I come across this performance of "All that Jazz" by Julie Steincke: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scdu88ln_Q4 (I am enchanted with it). I do not recognize the language, but since Julie Steincke is Danish, I suppose it is also Danish.

I do not know Danish. I have searched the internet, but I could not find any lyrics for this performance.

Does someone know whether I can find lyrics for it anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, it is Danish. I don't know about official lyrics; this is my transcription based on listening to it. There are two lines in the third stanza, marked with *s, where I'm not 100% certain what exactly she's singing, but the meaning is mostly obvious.

```
Kom nu skat, jeg ved et særligt sted
Og alt det jazz
Jeg fylder glasset op og ruller strømpen ned
Og alt det jazz
Start din bil, jeg ved det bli'r så godt
Deres gin er kold, men deres musik er hot
Og det kan godt blive hedt, der hvor man danser tæt
Og alt det jazz

Hatten på, og dine dansesko
Og alt det jazz
Der er et særligt band, og deres Blues er go'
Og alt det jazz
Bare skænk op, vi nærmer to i træk
Og danser natten varm og hovedpinen væk
Og dine tømmermænd bli'r hurtigt glemt igen
Og alt det jazz

Den her fest, den er sgu langt fra slut
Og alt det jazz
La' nu vær og sig du har fortrudt
Og alt det jazz
Kom nu skat, se hvor min kjole er kort *
Og hver en dum bekymring får vi [aet?] bort *
Det her har ingen set, husk nu sket er sket
Og alt det jazz

[Repeat 1st stanza]

Jeg er ikke naiv, jeg kæmper for mit liv
Og alt det jazz
Det jazz
```

Here's my rough translation (not as catchy as the original, obviously).

```
Come on darling, I know a special place
And all that jazz
I fill the glass and roll down the sock
And all that jazz
Start your car, I know it'll be so good
Their gin is cold, but their music is hot
And it might get hot where you're dancing close
And all that jazz

Put on your hat, and your dancing shoes
And all that jazz
There is a special [or certain] band, and their Blues is good
And all that jazz
Just fill up [the glass], we approach two in a row
And dance the night warm and the headache away
And your hangover is soon forgotten again
And all that jazz

This party, it is far from over
And all that jazz
Don't say your feet have gone cold [that you've regretted]
And all that jazz
Come on darling, see how my skirt/dress is short
And every silly worry/concern we'll soon [caress?] away
No one saw this, remember: what's done is done
And all that jazz

[Repeat 1st stanza]

I am not naive, I'm fighting for my life
And all that jazz
That jazz
```

Comment: I almost lost hope. Thank you! I've listened to the song before a while; Danish seems not so hard to pronounce. — I've accepted and given a point (I wish I could give more than one for your work; either way, I have < 15 reputation, so my vote is not displayed).

Comment: @Silv You're welcome :) It was a lucky coincidence that I noticed the question at all